# Using absolute path with streamwriter C#

Tags: c#, streamwriter, absolute-path

I am trying to use streamwriter to create a text file in the my documents folder, however it thinks i am using a relative path when i am actually using a full path.

I am trying to create the file using this path: "%HOMEPATH%/My Documents/", but it treats this as a relative path.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use [`Environment.GetFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx) - which in this case would avoid you hard-coding `My Documents` at all:

```
string docs = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
```

If you wanted to get a directory name relative to that, you should use [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx):

```
string fooDocsDirectory = Path.Combine(docs, "foo");
```

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to get a users' Documents folder in .Net is to use [`Environment.GetFolderPath()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx) and pass in `Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments`.

Answer (score 3):

Use [System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) to get to the My Documents path, rather than attempting to use system variables.

Answer (score 0):

I would resolve the environment variable using some API and then input the path that includes the absolute path ("C:.....") to the [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fysy0a4b.aspx)

You could use [Environment.SpecialFolder Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) as suggested by David Staratton.

Answer (score 0):

Check the environment variables from the command prompt. I see the following on my machine -

HOMEDRIVE=C:

HOMEPATH=\Users\foo

So try %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH% instead to fix your problem